# How do i merge this integer value with array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and an integer value.

```
$amenityIds = array('1','2','3','4','5');
$propertyId = 1;
```

What I want is the integer value to be added to the first array after each and every key like the code below.

```
array('1','1','2','1','3','1','4','1','5','1')
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `$propertyId` isn't an array, so you aren't merging two arrays. Can it ever be an array, or will it always be a value?

Comment: you forgot the second array my friend

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: you want the value of every element in the array `$amenityIds` to be equal to `1`?

Comment: i am really sorry guys for the wrong question title, i have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($amenityIds as $key => $value){
    $newArray[] = $value;
    $newArray[] = $propertyId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing, but you can get that result by doing this. Don't know any more pre-fab way:

```
foreach($amenityIds as $amenityId){
   $newArray[] = $amenityId;
   $newArray[] = $propertyId; //'1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$amenityIds = array('1','2','3','4','5');
$propertyId = 1;

$result = array();
foreach($amenityIds as $id) {
    $result[] = $id;
    $result = array_merge($result, (array)$propertyId);
}
```

This supports `$propertyId` being an array.